# Prevent methods from being intercepted - castle

Tags: castle-windsor, castle-dynamicproxy

When I assign an interceptor to the component when registering it (interface based), every method that is part of the interface contract gets intercepted. Is there a way prevent a method from being intercepted an attribute or something?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

DP uses [`IProxyGenerationHook`s](http://kozmic.pl/archive/2009/01/17/castle-dynamic-proxy-tutorial-part-iii-selecting-which-methods-to.aspx) to decide which method should be intercepted.

You can come up with your own attribute type and decorate your methods with it, and have a hook that will act accordingly based on the attribute. Or not use attributes at all and have some other logic to decide whether or not to intercept a method. It's up to you. DP won't constrain you here.

Comment: I came across this article of your on Selecting which methods to
intercept which shows an implementation of ProxyGenerationOptions with
ProxyGenerationHook. I am using windsor container and register types
as follow

IWindsorContainer container = new WindsorContainer();
container.Register(Component.For<IFoo>().ImplementedBy<Foo>());

could you please indicate how can i register ProxyGenerationOptions 
using windsor container. Thanks